# How to add KWGT android kustom widget functionality in react native

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, react-native-bridge

I'm new in the react-native and making an app for wallpaper and Android custom widgets.
My requirement is a list of widgets shown when I click the widget it should open in kwgtPro editor.
Kwgt Pro is a library of Kotlin. so how do I implement this in the React native?

References (Zooper,Nova Launcher, Kwgt widgets).

I also read it would be done using the native-bridge in the react native but I don't understand.
any one help me thanks in advance.